# Setting YAML variables depending on trigger branch

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to get my head around the yaml syntax for defining build pipelines in devops.

I'd like to set variables in the file dependent on which branch triggered the build.

```
# trigger:
 batch: true
 branches:
   include:
    - master
    - develop
    - staging

 variables:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release' # Can I set this according to the branch which triggered the build?
```

I've tried the following but can't seem to define variables twice.

```
 variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'

 variables:
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop')
  buildConfiguration: 'Develop'

 variables:
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release')
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
```

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably add a script step to calculate those. so create some sort of script that will check the value of $(Build.SourceBranch) and set the value of `buildConfiguration` like you normally would:

```
echo '##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration]something'
```

Comment: Thank you. I've not come across those yet. Reading time.

Comment: just look at the `variables` article for azure devops, it has info about those. basically all you have to do is echo out a string that looks like that

Comment: Thank you. I've stumbled across this for setting up multiple YAML files... but it seems a bit clunky so I'll try with the variables. https://sethreid.co.nz/using-multiple-yaml-build-definitions-azure-devops/

Answer (score 9):

If anyone's interested, I ended up with this.

```
 trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
   include:
    - master
    - develop

[truncated] 

 #https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-job-scoped-variable-from-a-script    
 - pwsh: |
    If ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/master") {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;]Release"
    }
    If ("$(Build.SourceBranch)" -eq "refs/heads/develop") {
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=buildConfiguration;]Debug"
    }
 - script: | 
    echo building configuration $(buildConfiguration)

 - task: VSBuild@1
   inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    vsVersion: '15.0'
```

Comment: under where does this pwsh come exactly?

Comment: This is the full file. It is in azure-pipelines.yml in the root of my project https://gist.github.com/damiensawyer/8c7f70fc3eff720631be964d1d3bfd2e